# How do you register to try the Pilot: Scratch Org Snapshots?

Tags: salesforcedx-cli

I want to try this feature how do i register to try this
Pilot: Scratch Org Snapshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic search for "Salesforce pilot programs" in your search engine of choice should reveal [this help article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000333128&type=1)

Quoting from it

> #### How to be a part of a Salesforce Feature Pilot
>
> To be nominated to participate in a pilot program, contact your Salesforce.com account rep or Customer Support via help.salesforce.com.
>
> Each nomination is evaluated individually, and orgs that are accepted into the program will be asked to sign a non-GA agreement.
>
> Note: Timelines vary due to the amount of review each request is given.